# How can I remove a property from an object?

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
  {"wordFormId":"abandon",
   "wordFormIdentity":1,
   "ascii":97,
   "wordId":"abandon",
   "primary":true,
   "posId":2}
```

How can I remove the ascii property? I know I could set it to null but I assume it would then still be there. What I would like to do is to completely remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

```
delete myObject.ascii;
// or,
delete myObject['ascii'];
```